# Process 'command 'SDK directory\build-tools\28.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I want to learn android and I use intellij.
untill last night it works but today when I run my project it say:

```
Process 'command 'C:\Users\Saleh\Downloads\Compressed\a\aaa\build-tools\28.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

what should I do??

Comment: Please try to remove .gradle folder and reimport project

Comment: @y.bedrov how can i remove gradle folder????

Comment: removing.. gradle folder not working